# ASP.NET Core permament redirect when no path specified

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, redirect, http-redirect, response.redirect

Is this a right way of doing permanent redirect when no path specified for request?

```
        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Path))
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Scheme, "site to redirect");
                context.Response.Redirect(builder.ToString(), true);
            }
            return next(context);
        });
```

Update 1

It appears that `context.Request.Path` includes `/`

```
        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Length <= 1)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Scheme, "www.plaMobi.com");
                context.Response.Redirect(builder.ToString(), true);
            }
            return next(context);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [UriHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/UriHelper.cs) implementation, both `HttpRequest.PathBase` abd `HttpRequest.Path` should be used:

```
var combinedPath = (pathBase.HasValue || path.HasValue) 
                   ? (pathBase + path).ToString() : "/";
```

The same logic in [ProxyMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs) class:

```
var uriString = $"{_options.Scheme}://{_options.Host}:{_options.Port}{context.Request.PathBase}{context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";
```